# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT
  ride_id,
  rideable_type,
  started_at,
  ended_at,
  start_station_name,
  start_station_id,
  end_station_name,
  end_station_id,
  start_lat,
  start_lng,
  end_lat,
  end_lng,
  member_casual,
  ride_length,
  ride_date,
  ride_month,
  ride_year,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  CAST(day_of_week AS STRING) AS day_of_week,
  quarter
FROM
  `my-data-project12345-368309.cyclistic_jamesbimler.2022_Q1`
UPDATE
  `my-data-project12345-368309.cyclistic_jamesbimler.2022_Q1`
SET
  day_of_week =
    CASE
      WHEN day_of_week = '1' THEN 'Sunday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '2' THEN 'Monday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '3' THEN 'Tuesday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '5' THEN 'Thursday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '6' THEN 'Friday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '7' THEN 'Saturday'
    END

WHERE
    day_of_week IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

I'm trying to change the day_of_week column from an int to a string to represent the days of the week but I keep getting the error Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier

I have tried to move code around and delete things with no luck.

Comment: have you tried to check the syntax for update statement?

Comment: I tried looking up the syntax on various help websites and I’m not seeing anything. I tried to simplify my SET argument and it still won’t work.

Comment: check this one on BigQuery Documentation site - [Update Statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) It has all you need to get through

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I was able to figure it out with your link!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. There is a syntax error missing semicolon, it is added.

```
SELECT
  ride_id,
  rideable_type,
  started_at,
  ended_at,
  start_station_name,
  start_station_id,
  end_station_name,
  end_station_id,
  start_lat,
  start_lng,
  end_lat,
  end_lng,
  member_casual,
  ride_length,
  ride_date,
  ride_month,
  ride_year,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  CAST(day_of_week AS STRING) AS day_of_week,
  quarter
FROM
  `my-data-project12345-368309.cyclistic_jamesbimler.2022_Q1`;

UPDATE
  `my-data-project12345-368309.cyclistic_jamesbimler.2022_Q1`
SET
  day_of_week =
    CASE
      WHEN day_of_week = '1' THEN 'Sunday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '2' THEN 'Monday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '3' THEN 'Tuesday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '5' THEN 'Thursday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '6' THEN 'Friday'
      WHEN day_of_week = '7' THEN 'Saturday'
    END

WHERE
    day_of_week IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');
```